# Dataframe append with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe d1 with multiindex of col1 and col2:

```
              col3   col4   col5
col1   col2  
  1      2      3      4      5
  2      3      4      5      6
```

And another dataframe d2 with exact same structure:

```
              col3   col4   col5
col1   col2  
 20     30     40     50     60
  2      3     44     55     66
```

How to do d1.append(d2), to make it become, which override the previous keys:

```
              col3   col4   col5
col1   col2  
  1      2      3      4      5
 20     30     40     50     60
  2      3     44     55     66
```

Comment: Another not quite related question. Is there anyway to set index columns when creating the data frame. For example, when I create the above d1, I don't need to create DF first, then call function set_index, but I can directly specify col1 & col2 are the index columns.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `combine_first`

```
out = d2.combine_first(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas.concat` with keep last

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=[0, 1]).last()
```

@BENY's answer is more user friendly and readable.